# Checking collisions of object in inspector shows true while in condition is shows false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright so, I'm trying to create a script that checks if there is a plane around my current plane. How do I do that? Instantiate 4 cube colliders around the current plane with this script on them:

```
public bool collided = false;
public GameObject collidedPlane;

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll){
      if(coll.gameObject.layer == 3){ // 3 is the collision layer I'm checking
          collided = true;
          collidedPlane = coll.gameObject;
      }
  }
  
  public bool isCollided(){
        if(collided) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

I've tried it out, it worked as intended after it ran and checked it myself (I checked the bool collided in the inspector)

But when trying to check the boolean or use the function isCollided (which is a way I tried fixing this problem) in code they both return false values.

I try checking in here(there are 4 of such instances but i only put one cause they are the same pretty much)

```
currentlyInstantiated = InstantiationPlace(-20, 0, colliderCheck); //Instantiate gameObject
if(currentlyInstantiated.GetComponent<CollidedWithWho>().isCollided()) //Check the collided bool
  //Something happens
```

Where InstantiationPlace is this small function

```
GameObject InstantiationPlace(int x, int z, GameObject theObject) {
  return Instantiate(theObject, currentRoomPosition + new Vector3(x, 0, z), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

And colliderCheck is the gameObject prefab that has the script and collider + rigidbody on.

I don't know what the problem is as it shows that the boolean is true when I check it and if it's a timing issue where the boolean is checked before OnTriggerEnter runs how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the boolean after OnTriggerEnter runs. [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Your `isCollided` is completely redundant ... Your flag `collided` already is public anyway ... I would rather make it `private` and have a read-only **property** `public bool isCollided => collided;` or even not use it at all ... If `collidedPlane` is not null you already know you are collided as well

Comment: The point is that neither way works as it always returns false although when I check it it's true, the function from the start was made by me to "try" and help the situation @derHugo